# Pull data from a workbook's worksheets into same column of another workbook's worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

Data will be received from clients, with different formats, in an Excel file.

Usually the file will have more than three sheets and multiple columns in each sheet. I need particular columns. I want to copy the required columns to an Analysis file's particular sheet.

My code interactively shows a userform where users provide the sheets and column number from where VBA will take data and capture the userform data for reference in the Analysis file.

If users select more than 5-6 columns it is difficult to copy to another file in same sheet, sometimes in same column which has to adjust & paste dynamically below the existing data. Per my understanding, I can't copy only the data from the selected column. It copies whole column and while pasting and is not allowing to paste dynamically in the existing column.

**Userform:**

```vb
Option Explicit
    
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    
    Dim myColumn As Integer
    Dim eRow
    Dim mySheet As Integer
    Dim mySheet2 As Integer
    Dim myColumn2 As Integer
    Dim eRow2
    
    mySheet = Val(TextBox2.Text)
    Sheets(mySheet).Select
    myColumn = Val(TextBox1.Text)
    Columns(myColumn).Copy
    
    
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    
    eRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    Cells(eRow, 1) = TextBox1.Text
    
    mySheet2 = Val(TextBox8.Text)
    Sheets(mySheet2).Select
    myColumn2 = Val(TextBox6.Text)
    Columns(myColumn2).Copy
    
    
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    
    eRow2 = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    Cells(eRow2, 1) = TextBox6.Text
    
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("E4").Value = mySheet
    
    MsgBox ("Client data has been successfully added,vbOKOnly")
    
End Sub
```

**Module Code:**

```vb
Option Explicit
    
Public Sub Main()
    
    Dim myUserForm As UserForm1
    Dim FileToOpen As Variant
    Dim OpenBook As Workbook
    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim rng As Range
    
    
    FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Browse for your File & Import Range")
    
    If FileToOpen <> False Then
        Set OpenBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)
    
        Set myUserForm = New UserForm1
        myUserForm.Show
    
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can copy data from a specific range instead of a whole column. You juste have to change your Columns(myColumn).Copy for something like Range(myRange).Copy.

If you are getting your data from a range, make sure that the column where you're pasting the data in doesn't contain any old data. Since it will only overwrite the data in your copied range which might be smaller than the destination range.

If you want to dynamically choose the destination. You can use something like this:  `Range(myRange).end(xldown).offset(1,0).paste xlvalues`

The idea is "end" is going to find the last line which has data on it. "Offset" is going to give the cell under it and that's your destination.

Here's a link to the documentation for these properties:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.end

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.offset

Comment: I have tried copying range instead of column but still I could not solve the issue.  Will there be any solution to paste dynamically a line below the existing data?

Comment: I'm not sure if it counts as a separate question, but I can edit my answer to say something about dynamically choosing the line in which to paste data

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you wan to upgrade to a database.  The code below will import Data from All Worksheets in All EXCEL Files in a single Folder into Separate Tables via TransferSpreadsheet (VBA)...

```
    Dim blnHasFieldNames As Boolean, blnEXCEL As Boolean, blnReadOnly As Boolean
    Dim intWorkbookCounter As Integer
    Dim lngCount As Long
    Dim objExcel As Object, objWorkbook As Object
    Dim colWorksheets As Collection
    Dim strPath As String, strFile As String
    Dim strPassword As String

    ' Establish an EXCEL application object
    On Error Resume Next
    Set objExcel = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
          Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
          blnEXCEL = True
    End If
    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo 0

    ' Change this next line to True if the first row in EXCEL worksheet
    ' has field names
    blnHasFieldNames = False

    ' Replace C:\MyFolder\ with the actual path to the folder that holds the EXCEL files
    strPath = "C:\MyFolder\"

    ' Replace passwordtext with the real password;
    ' if there is no password, replace it with vbNullString constant
    ' (e.g., strPassword = vbNullString)
    strPassword = "passwordtext"

    blnReadOnly = True ' open EXCEL file in read-only mode

    strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.xls")

    intWorkbookCounter = 0

    Do While strFile <> ""

          intWorkbookCounter = intWorkbookCounter + 1

          Set colWorksheets = New Collection

          Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(strPath & strFile, , _
                blnReadOnly, , strPassword)

          For lngCount = 1 To objWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
                colWorksheets.Add objWorkbook.Worksheets(lngCount).Name
          Next lngCount

          ' Close the EXCEL file without saving the file, and clean up the EXCEL objects
          objWorkbook.Close False
          Set objWorkbook = Nothing

          ' Import the data from each worksheet into a separate table
          For lngCount = colWorksheets.Count To 1 Step -1
                DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, _
                      "tbl" & colWorksheets(lngCount) & intWorkbookCounter, _
                      strPath & strFile, blnHasFieldNames, _
                      colWorksheets(lngCount) & "$"
          Next lngCount

          ' Delete the collection
          Set colWorksheets = Nothing

          ' Uncomment out the next code step if you want to delete the
          ' EXCEL file after it's been imported
          ' Kill strPath & strFile

          strFile = Dir()

    Loop

    If blnEXCEL = True Then objExcel.Quit
    Set objExcel = Nothing
```

Reference URL is below:

http://www.accessmvp.com/KDSnell/EXCEL_Import.htm#ImpAllWkshts